# How do i prove that continuous linear transformation between normed spaces is bounded?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Let $(V,||\cdot||_V),(W,||\cdot||_W)$ be normed spaces over $\mathbb{C}$.

Let $T:V\rightarrow W$ be a linear transformation.

Assume $T$ is continuous.

Then, how do i prove that $\exists c>0$ such that $\forall v\in V, ||Tv||_W<c||v||_V$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$T$ is continuous.  Let $\epsilon = 1$.  We can find $\delta$ so that $||Tv|| < 1$ when $||v|| < \delta$.

Now, $||Tv|| = || \frac{||v||}{\delta} T(\frac{\delta v}{||v||})|| \leq \frac{||v||}{\delta}$.  Take $c = \frac{1}{\delta}$.

Comment: Question: can we maintain strict inequality here? That is, is $|| \frac{||v||}{\delta} T(\frac{\delta v}{||v||})|| \lt \frac{||v||}{\delta}$ true?

Answer (score 2):

Alternative proof by contradiction. Suppose for all $k$ there is some $v_k\neq 0$ such that $\|T v_k \| \ge k \|v_k\|$.

Let $x_k = {1 \over k} { v_k \over \|v_k\|}$, and note that $\|T x_k \| \ge 1$, but $x_k \to 0$, which contradicts continuity.